# How to calculate the average of the average in PowerBI using DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, average

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have a table which record the percentage of attendance as shown in the screenshot. I want to calculate the average attendance rate of all the events by following method:

`average attendance rate for event 1 = (12% + 7% + 15%)/3 = 11.33%`

`average attendance rate for event 2 = (22% + 37%)/2 = 29.5%`

`average attendance rate for event 3 = 10%`

`average attendance rate for event 2 = (14% + 15%)/2 = 14.5%`

**Final result:**

`Total average attendance rate for all events = (11.33% + 29.5% + 10% + 14.5%)/4 = 16.33%`

The final output that I want is `16.33%`, couldn't figure out how to use DAX to get the final output that I want. The final output will be used in Card visualization.

I'm aware that I can put the `Attendance rate` column directly into card visualization and get the average attendance rate which is 16.5%, but this is not the way that I'm interested. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
Event   Attendance rate
event 1 12.00%
event 1 7.00%
event 1 15.00%
event 2 22.00%
event 2 37.00%
event 3 10.00%
event 4 14.00%
event 4 15.00%
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate average win rate among all the student using DAX in PowerBI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72674108/how-to-calculate-average-win-rate-among-all-the-student-using-dax-in-powerbi)

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work for this case

Comment: Please paste your sample data as text.

Comment: I edited my question with sample data at the bottom, thanks

Comment: did you try like `Average(tbl[Rate])` ? or you want a measure that calculates aver for each event and then aver of aver?

Comment: `or you want a measure that calculates aver for each event and then aver of aver?` Yes, this is what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The inner CALCULATE(AVERAGE()) computes aver for each event value (event1, event2 ...)
2. AVERAGEX() computes aver among 1.

---

```
  cardMeasure=    
  AVERAGEX(
           VALUES(tbl[Event])
           ,CALCULATE(AVERAGE(tbl[Attendance rate]))
 )
```

Answer (score 2):

First you can create a Calculated Table (Menu--> Modelling--> New Table) which you may need to use.

```
Average of Data = 
 SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('Table (Average)'[Event],
                            "Average of Events", AVERAGE('Table (Average)'[Attendance rate]))
```

Then create the measure under this table

```
Average of Average = AVERAGE('Average of Data'[Average of Events])
```

[image: Average of Average]

Answer (score 1):

Hello Please try this measure:

```
    Average_Attendance_Rate =
    VAR Calc_01 =
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            VALUES ( YourTbl[Event] ),
            "Average", CALCULATE ( ROUND ( AVERAGE ( YourTbl[Attendance rate] ), 4 ) )
        )
    VAR Result =
        AVERAGEX ( Calc_01, [Average] )
    RETURN       
    Result
 --OR FORMAT ( Result, "Percent" )
```

The result :

[image: GGG]

Comment: you are faster )))